# Show That $\sum_{K=1}^{n}\frac{X_k}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}}$ If ${X_n}$ is $X_k$s Same Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, independence, stable-distribution

> Let ${\{X_n}\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables and the
> stable distribution of order alpha $(0\le\alpha\le2)$.
>
> Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{X_k}{n^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}}$$ if
> ${X_n}$ is $X_k$s same distribution.

I can't find anywhere this theory. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Although it seems clear what you're trying to ask, your text is really garbled.  Could you edit it to make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This is only true if the location parameter is zero.

(In which case you can use the characteristic function of the stable distribution $e^{-|ct|^\alpha (1-i\beta sign(t) tan(\pi\alpha/2))}$ to prove it for $\alpha\neq 1$)

As a counter example consider the normal distribution (for which $\alpha=2$)

$$Y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

In this case you have $\sigma_Y = \sigma_X$ but $\mu_Y \neq \mu_X$ and instead $\mu_Y = \sqrt{n} \mu_X$. So $Y$ is not similarly distributed as $X$ (it is the same family though, maybe that is what you meant).